# Python - Testing an authenticated user with PyTest/Flask-User

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-login, flask-user

I'm trying to set up pytests for my Flask-User based application but struggling to figure out how to log in as a user to test my routes.

Current test_app.py

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def app():
    from app import create_app
    app = create_app()
    yield app

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client(app):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_logged_in_member(client):
    # Log in as the 'member' user
    response = client.post('/user/sign-in', data={
        'username': 'member',
        'password': 'Password1'
    }, follow_redirects=True)  # Enable automatic redirect following
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'You have signed in successfully.' in response.data
```

I would expect this to follow the redirect back to the home page where the success message is displayed, but I get this response back from pytest:

```
test_app.py::test_logged_in_member failed: client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'app'>>

    def test_logged_in_member(client):
        # Log in as the 'member' user
        response = client.post('/user/sign-in', data={
            'username': 'member',
            'password': 'Password1'
        }, follow_redirects=True)  # Enable automatic redirect following
        assert response.status_code == 200
>       assert b'You have signed in successfully.' in response.data
E       assert b'You have signed in successfully.' in b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" cont...ript src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>\n\n    \n    \n\n  </body>\n</html>'
E        +  where b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" cont...ript src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>\n\n    \n    \n\n  </body>\n</html>' = <WrapperTestResponse 3942 bytes [200 OK]>.data

test_app.py:75: AssertionError
```

This response data doesn't look right to me, and I can't figure out where the data is coming from, so either it's not redirecting correctly or my request is just nonsense.

Ideally I want to be in a position to run a test as one of the two users already in the sqlite database to check access levels on the various routes, but as I say I can't figure out how to persist a log in. Any Flask wizards able to help me out here?

Many Thanks,